# Documents are not visible with Read rights in SharePoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013 and I created a DocLibrary with the site collection admin account. I added a .docx file directly in it, but all the users (all in the same SharePoint group) that have only the Read permissions do not see the file. If I switch their permissions on this library to anything else (Edit, Contribute, etc.) they can see the file. The permissions on the document are inherited from the library.

Also, I did not change anything in the Central Admin Permission Policy.

My question is: why users cannot see documents with Read permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **Versionning Settings** of the library, "**Who should see draft items in this document library**" was set to "**Only users who can edit items**", so I switched it to "**Any user who can read items**". 
Even if content approval was *disabled*, the document was considered as a draft and the rule was applied.

Below are the complete steps for follow:
http://sharepointbag.com/latest/blogs/sharepoint/list-and-libraries/13/documents-are-not-visible-to-users-with-read-permissions-in-sharepoint-2013-document-library/

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution to this problem.
May be it is access related error but beore changing anything in the versionning settings you also do onething.
First select the document then click on the ... part then a pop-up will come where again click on the ... part, a list of options will be showed. There click 'Publish Document', once it is published then users having the read access will also be able to se the document.

And if publishing is done and still it is not visible to Read Users then follow https://superuser.com/users/203404/luapaul's way.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Default view for SP List is "All items" which is a datasheet type of view, and opens in edit mode directly. Add new "Standard view" and set it as default. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same issue. It turns out the user never checked the files in. I had to take ownership and check them all in manually.